# SQL query -- not getting expected result using ALL and '=' operator

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, where-clause

I have a table:

```
id  name
1   A
3   B
2   C
4   D
```

I am trying to select a few rows using the following query in a stored procedure:

```
select * from test where id = all ('{1,2}');
```

I am expecting it to return rows with ids 1 and 2, however, it returns empty.

The following query works as expected:

```
select * from test where id <> all ('{3,4}');
```

It is returning rows with id 1 and 2. I am unable to understand why '=' operator is not working as expected but '<>' is working. I am new to this syntax. Please help how to get the expected result that is using equal operator (equivalent to IN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am expecting it to return rows with ids 1 and 2

You want `any`, not `all`:

```
where id = any ('{1,2}');
```

This brings `id` that are either equal to `1` or `2`. In other words that's equivalent to `id in (1, 2)`.

As regard to this expression:

```
where id <> all ('{3,4}');
```

This is equivalent to:

```
where not (id = any ('{3,4}'));
```

So this filters out `id`s `3` and `4`.

Concerning your original expression:

```
where id = all ('{1,2}');
```

This does not make sense; a single value cannot be matched against all values of an array at once - so this filters out all rows.